# Debug can't print results to file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging

i'm using python 3.8 on ubuntu 20.04, and I cant get the DEBUG statements to log to my other file, my code -

```
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename = 'logDEBUG.txt') 

def say(x):
    print(x)

phrase = 'hi'

logging.debug(say(phrase))
```

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything.

Comment: `print` writes to stdout not to a file. You just need to return: `return x`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value, not print it.

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename = 'logDEBUG.txt') 

def say(x):
    return x

phrase = 'hi'

logging.debug(say(phrase))
```

Result in *logDEBUG.txt*:

```
DEBUG:root:hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the problem that the file is not created?
If so check to see what your python path is, i don't know if you expect that the log file should appear in the same folder as your script.

Search for the file on your computer and see where it ends up.